# Laravel polymorphic type not stored correctly

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I'm using Backpack to create an Admin Panel for my project. I have a SoldProduct model (basically a physical item that has been sold to a customer), a Shoe model and a Sweatshirt model.
There is a polymorphic relationship between them in order to have a separate table for each one of them, avoiding the repetition of the columns that they share and also avoiding the (kinda ugly) solution of storing them ina big table that has got all the necessary fields that would remain partially null based on the type of product it's being stored.

Since I'm using Backpack's CRUD, I created a custom store method that creates the specific types of product and then creates a SoldProduct object linked to the specific one (by filling the productable_type ansd productable_id fields).

The problem is that while `productable_id` is stored correctly, in the `productable_type` field instead of storing for example `"App\Models\Shoe"` I keep getting `"App\Models\SoldProduct"` (the parent model's name), and I don't know where it's getting it from. The data is passed correctly to the "final" store method, but in the process of storing it gets modified in `"App\Models\SoldProduct"`.

Any clue on why this might be happening? Thanks everybody.

Here's my code

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->crud->setRequest($this->crud->validateRequest()); 
    $productable_type = $request->request->get('productable_type');

    switch ($productable_type) {
        case "Shoe":
            $product = new Shoe;
            $product->imprinted_code = $request->request->get('imprinted_code');
            $product->size = $request->request->get('shoe_size');
            $product->sole = $request->request->get('sole');

            $product->save();

            $product_id = $product->id;

            $this->crud->addField(['type' => 'hidden', 'name' => 'productable_id']);
            $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['productable_id' => "$product_id"]);
            $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['productable_type' => "App\Models\\$productable_type"]); 

            break;
    // repeat for Sweatshirt too
    } 

    $this->removeField('imprinted_code', $request);
    $this->removeField('shoe_size', $request);
    $this->removeField('sole', $request);
    $this->removeField('sweatshirt_size', $request);
    $this->removeField('shirt_size', $request);
    $this->removeField('pants_size', $request); 

    $this->crud->unsetValidation();

    return $this->traitStore();
}
```

sold_products_table

```
Schema::create('sold_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->id();
       $table->foreignId('product_model_id')->constrained('product_models');
       $table->foreignId('owner_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
       $table->integer('productable_id')->nullable();
       $table->string('productable_type')->nullable();
       $table->string('note')->nullable();
       $table->timestamps();
});
```

SoldProduct

```
public function productable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Shoe

```
public function product() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\SoldProduct', 'productable');
}
```

Sweatshirt

```
public function product() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\SoldProduct', 'productable');
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you storing the relationship? Why are you manually adding the morph fields to your request? Laravel should take care of that.

Comment: I'm manually adding the morph fields because using Backpack's CRUD, I can't automatically insert the specific product id, I have to first formulate the request and then, create the specific product, get its id and give it to the request that will create the SoldProduct

Comment: What's funny is that if I manipulate the productable_type string in such a way that it is wrong, for example without the namespace, so just "Shoe", the string is actually stores as it is but the relationship doesn't happen and the id isn't stored. If instead  Imanipulate it correctly, the id is stored but the productable_type becomes "App\Models\SoldProducts" for some reason.

Comment: so doing `$this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['productable_type' => "App\\Models\\Shoe"]); ` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it gets modified in "App\Models\SoldProduct"

Comment: I still don't see where it's saving the relationship model. Perhaps your logic is just wrong there.

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: I did it all over again by scratch and still `App\Models\Shoe` gets modified in `App\Models\SoldProduct`

Comment: Your code still does not show where the relationship is being saved.